# Acquiring coordinates readouts from an optical mouse ala wiimote (MATLAB code)

Tags: matlab, mouse, coordinates

I plan to get the x-y coordinated reading from an optical mouse. Basically, I want the readout to be something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5TmcnP0dLw) but instead of using a Wiimote, I'll be using a standard USB mouse.

I have found quite a good example - [http://www.synbio.org.uk/component/content/article/46-instrumentation-news/1234-interfacing-an-optical-mouse-sensor-to-your-arduino.html]

but sadly it runs on C++ and needs a bridging hardware called Arduino. Though however, it PRINTS out the coordinate rather than putting it into a 'real-time' graphical plot.

I would love if MATLAB can read off the coordinates from the mouse and plot a 'real-time' graph of the coordinates.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DLL or DLLs for communicating with your mouse you should be able to persuade Matlab to use it or them.  Look at the documentation for `loadlibrary`.

(Of course, if you are using Linux or Mac OS X replace 'DLL' with 'shared library'.)